# Reactflow EDGES not visible

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I have installed `react-flow`  in my existig react project as per instructions here https://reactflow.dev/ with package.json contents listed here;

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/humanize-duration": "^3.18.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.14",
    "@types/js-base64": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.162",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-modal": "1.6.8",
    "@types/react-select": "3.0.22",
    "ansi-to-react": "^5.1.1",
    "humanize-duration": "^3.24.0",
    "js-base64": "^2.6.4",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "protobufjs": "^6.10.2",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-flow-renderer": "^9.7.2",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-swipeable": "^5.5.1",
    "react-switch": "^5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.43.4",
    "swagger-parser": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.0.3",
    "xterm": "^3.14.5",
    "yaml": "^1.10.0"
  },
```

Everything renders perfectly fine but edges are not visible (even though I can see svg path in chrome inspector);

[image]

my component code is here that renders ReactFlow component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ReactFlow, {
  removeElements, addEdge,
  ReactFlowProvider,
  MiniMap,
  Controls,
  Background,
} from 'react-flow-renderer';

type Props = {

}

type State = {
  filter: string;
  elements: any[];
}

export default class Editor extends Component<Props, State> {

  state: State = {
    filter: '',
    elements: [
      {
        id: '1',
        type: 'input',
        data: {
          label: (
            <>
              Welcome to <strong>React Flow!</strong>
            </>
          ),
        },
        position: { x: 250, y: 0 },
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        data: {
          label: (
            <>
              This is a <strong>default node</strong>
            </>
          ),
        },
        position: { x: 100, y: 100 },
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        data: {
          label: (
            <>
              This one has a <strong>custom style</strong>
            </>
          ),
        },
        position: { x: 400, y: 100 },
        style: {
          background: '#D6D5E6',
          color: '#333',
          border: '1px solid #222138',
          width: 180,
        },
      },
      { id: 'e1-2', source: '1', target: '2', label: 'this is an edge label',arrowHeadType: 'arrowclosed', animated: true, type: 'smoothstep' },
      // { id: 'e1-3', source: '1', target: '3', labelStyle: { fill: '#f6ab6c', fontWeight: 700 },style: { zIndex:999, stroke: "red", strokeWidth: 30, cursor: "pointer" } }
    ]
  };

  onElementRemove(elem: any) {
    console.log(elem);
  }

  onConnect(params:any, comp:any){
    console.log(params);
    addEdge(params, comp)
  }

  onClick(ev:any, el:any, elem:any) {
      console.log(el);
    }
  
    onLoad(){
      console.log('loaded')
    }
    onNodeStrokeColor(n:any){
      if (n.style?.background) return n.style.background;
      if (n.type === 'input') return '#0041d0';
      if (n.type === 'output') return '#ff0072';
      if (n.type === 'default') return '#1a192b';

      return '#eee';
    }
    onNodeColor(n:any){
      if (n.style?.background) return n.style.background;
      return '#fff';
    }

  render() {
    const { elements, filter } = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={{ height: 300 }}>
        <ReactFlow elements={elements} 
        onElementsRemove={x=>this.onElementRemove(x)}
        onConnect={params => this.onConnect(params, elements)}
        onElementClick={(ev, el) =>this.onClick(ev, el, elements)}
        onlyRenderVisibleElements={false}
        deleteKeyCode={46}
        onLoad={this.onLoad}
        snapToGrid={true}
        snapGrid={[15, 15]}
        >
          <MiniMap style={{ width: 150, height:150 }}
            nodeStrokeColor={n => this.onNodeStrokeColor(n)}
            nodeColor={n => this.onNodeColor(n)}
            nodeBorderRadius={2}
      />
      <Controls />
      <Background color="#00a" gap={15} />
          </ReactFlow>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem and it turns out that I have a scss file that overrides SVG styles of react-flow-renderer

```
svg {
    ...
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

https://github.com/wbkd/react-flow/issues/1880